# Is there an easy way to replace a value based on index while broadcasting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

Let's suppose we have the following problem:

I want to accumulate minimum values in every row but ignoring the first value.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[5,4,4]])
b = np.arange(-2,7).reshape((3,-1))

x = a.astype(float)
x[:,0] = float('inf')

c = b == np.minimum.accumulate(x,axis=1)
print(c)
```

The above solution is easy, I simply copied the variable `a` into `x`, assigned the 0 element to *infinity*.

Then, passing it to `np.minimum.accumulate()` I get the result.

However there are two problems with this approach:

1. I have to define an extra variable `x`, which I will never be using again.
2. After defining the variable, I have to assign a value, that's two lines of code.

So the question is, how to avoid the `x` variable altogether?

Comment: Show some values, such as `x` and `c`, and even the `np.minimum...`.  That we don't have to run to the code to visualize what is happening.

Comment: So you want to do: `b[:,1:]==np.minimum.accumulate(a[:,1:], axis=1)`, with an added column of `False` at the start?  I wouldn't call this a particularly `broadcasting` issue.

Comment: The code is easy to visualize, have `a` and `b` and then I need one-liner `c` that results in 3 by 3 matrix with only `True` in the middle.

Comment: I have tried slicing the first element out before passing to the accumulate function but then we have an issue with the array shape. Doing `numpy.append` afterwards won't look pretty.

Comment: I want to have a simple solution, if only we rewrite the 0 element in `a` on the fly, like so: `np.minimum.accumulate(a[:,0]=inf,axis=1)` - this is just pseudo code.

Comment: There you have an answer that fulfills all the requirements... yet I would not accept it as a valid answer X-p

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not easy, simple nor nice, but at least it's a one-liner ;) and does not create intermediate variables. This requires at least Python 3.10 for the walrus operator:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,2,1],[5,4,4]])
b = np.arange(-2,7).reshape((3,-1))

(c := np.zeros_like(a, dtype=bool))[:,1:] = (b[:,1:] == np.minimum.accumulate(a.astype(float)[:,1:], axis=1))
print(c)
```

In versions < 3.10, it's a two-liner.